# Azure AD: How assign App roles for users from another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Let's imagine that I've created Application in **Tenant1** and it has "Accounts in any organizational director".

I need to declare in this app 3 roles: SuperAdmin, Admin, Reader.

It's clear how assign roles for users who belong to **Tenant1**, but is there any way to assign SuperAdmin role of Tenant1 app to user who belongs to **Tenant2**? Or how should it happen? I need to invite users in Tenant1 from Tenant2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will only be able to assign app roles to a user in the tenant where the application is used.

The answer would depend on in which Azure AD (Tenant 1 only or both Tenant 1 and Tenant 2) the application will be used. Or in other words, where the Service Principal for this application will be created - Tenant 1 only or both Tenant 1 and Tenant 2.

If the application is only used in Tenant 1, then you would have to invite the user from Tenant 2 into Tenant 1 and only then you will be able to assign app roles to that user.

However if the application is used in Tenant 2 as well, then you don't have to do anything special. Tenant 2 admins would be able to assign the desired app role to the users in their tenant.

Comment: If I create app for both Tenant1 and Tenant2 - in this way for SPA I need to develop some discovery mechanism on my own which would choose target clientId in the particular tenant. Am I correct?